# Eclipse project does not build with unhelpful error

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse is giving me a red X on a project.  I compared this project to a similar one in another workspace.  The classpath is different (it's supposed to be), and a few source files that are supposed to be.  But the error in the problems tab says

"The project was not built due to "". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent"

Yeah, that key spot where it seems like critical information would go just says "".  I tried refreshing and rebuilding to no avail.  The project is imported from outside the workspace.  But that shouldn't matter, should it?  I've done that before with no problems.  But a similar project (the one I am comparing to) works fine in the workspace.

Where else can I look for error info that might help me narrow this down?

update - This project is used by others as a project reference, but this project does not rely on others.  Here is it's classpath file contents:

```
    <classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.runtime.runtimeTarget.v70/was.base.v7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.utility"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path=".apt_generated">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/WebSphere Application Server v7.0 JRE">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/cecore.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/celib.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/ceplugins_client.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/ceplugins_core.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/ceplugins_cr.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/cereports.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/cesession.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/ceutils.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/aopalliance-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/apache-commons/commons-beanutils.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/apache-commons/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/apache-commons/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/apache-commons/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/corbaidl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/ebus405.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/hibernate/hibernate-3.5.1/hibernate3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/icu4j-3.4.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/jasypt-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/joda-time-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/jpa-api-2.0-cr-1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/junit-4.8.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/log4j-1.2.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/buisnessObjects/logging.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.aop-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.aspects-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.jms-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.orm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.oxm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.test-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.transaction-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/spring/spring-framework-3.0.1/org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/poi-3.7-beta3-20100924.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/serialization.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/SL_plugins.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/misc3rdParty/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-auth-roles-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-datetime-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-devutils-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-extensions-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-guice-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-ioc-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-jmx-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-objectsizeof-agent-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-spring-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/views/SharedComp_Development/SharedComp_Software/jar/wicket/wicket-1.4.7/wicket-velocity-1.4.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the project has a dependency defined but the project name was removed. This can be done with the .classpath file is manually edited. I would try to remove all the dependent projects from the .classpath file.

You can do this from Eclipse by editing the build path and removing any projects. Then add the dependent proejcts back. This should clean up the .classpath file.

Comment: This project is included by others, it does not include projects.

Comment: Then I would try adding a dependency and removing it to try to clean up the .project file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zagrev for helping, but it turns out, someone had checked our bin folder into our integrated source control and so eclipse wasn't actually able to compile the code.  Once I deleted the bin and it could generate, it generated fine and the error went away.

Still, FANTASTICALLY unhelpful message there eclipse.  Had the message directed me towards unwritable class files, I'd probably have found it right away.  Instead I floundered for hours trying to figure out what was wrong with my .classpath or .settings.